# Validation Rule should accept only Alphabets and Numbers

Tags: formula, validation, validation-rule

```
NOT(
    OR(LEN(Tax_ID__c) = 0,REGEX(Tax_ID__c, "[a-zA-Z0-9-' ']+"))) && 
    (CONTAINS(Tax_ID__c, '')) && 
    ISNULL( Tax_ID__c )
)
```

I have the above `Validation Rule` whose aim is to accept only Alphabetic and Numeric characters. But it is accepting other characters.

**Edit** <sub><sup>(from comments)</sup></sub>

I just figured out it is Encrypted field. Sorry for the confusion. It is encrypted through an external application (not Salesforce default encryption field).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NOT(
   OR(
       REGEX(AlphaNumeric_Field__c, "(\\D)+(\\d)+"),          
       REGEX(AlphaNumeric_Field__c,"[^%$#@&!*()^+_-]"),
       REGEX(AlphaNumeric_Field__c,"[^=,<.>/?~`]")
   )
)
```

Check this and let me know if it is working?

Comment: Hi Amol and Ratan,

It is working good. Thanks